# Grouping of rows in a dataframe based on the date column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use groupby to group the below data based on similar date rows with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
df = df.reset_index()       
df = df.groupby(on='date')
```

I am not able to get the correct syntax to work:

Input:

[image: Input Data]

Expecting Result:

[image: Expected result]

Can someone provide me some pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `bfill` and `ffill`. Then drop duplicates.

To group by your index, use `level=0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017/06/22', 49.8, 281.6, np.nan],
                   ['2017/06/22', np.nan, np.nan, 36.1],
                   ['2017/06/23', 49.6, 280.2, np.nan],
                   ['2017/06/23', np.nan, np.nan, 35.9]],
                  columns=['date', 'ratio', 'local', 'usd'])

df = df.set_index('date')
g = df.groupby(level=0)
df = g.bfill().ffill().drop_duplicates()

print(df)

            ratio  local   usd
date                          
2017/06/22   49.8  281.6  36.1
2017/06/23   49.6  280.2  35.9
```